# Strategy pattern c#, how to check if passed enum value match any of possible parameters, so strategy would be evaluated

Tags: c#, enums, strategy-pattern

```
public TeklaViewTypes ViewType => TeklaViewTypes.FrontView | TeklaViewTypes.TopView | TeklaViewTypes.BottomView;
```

passed ViewType should check if it is equal to any of TeklaViewTypes.FrontView | TeklaViewTypes.TopView | TeklaViewTypes.BottomView.

So far it works only with one possible option.

Comment: You need to define "any of possible parameters". Any value of the backing integer type is valid. I assume that is not your definition of any possible value. So define that first anf than do a & operation between that value and ViewType  and see if its different from 0.

Comment: Is `=> TeklaViewTypes.FrontView | TeklaViewTypes.TopView | TeklaViewTypes.BottomView;` real code, or pseudo code and you're showing possible values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need TeklaViewTypes to be a binary ('flags') enum, and then you just need to use & as shown in the code below.  The key line is `if ((test & ViewType) == test)`.

```
    [Flags]
    enum TeklaViewTypes
    {
        FrontView = 1,
        TopView = 2,
        BottomView = 4,
        InvalidView = 8
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            TeklaViewTypes[] testArray = { 
                TeklaViewTypes.FrontView,   // Pass
                TeklaViewTypes.TopView,     // Pass 
                TeklaViewTypes.BottomView,  // Pass
                TeklaViewTypes.InvalidView, // Fail
            };
            foreach (TeklaViewTypes test in testArray)
                CheckViewType(test);
        }

        private void CheckViewType(TeklaViewTypes test)
        {
            if ((test & ViewType) == test)
                Console.WriteLine($"{test}: Pass");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"{test}: Fail");
        }

        public TeklaViewTypes ViewType =>
            TeklaViewTypes.FrontView | TeklaViewTypes.TopView | TeklaViewTypes.BottomView;
    }
```